# Algebraic Geometry: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

This may be a very stupid question. But please explain what I am doing  wrong.

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $f\in k[x_1,\dots, x_n]$.

Let $$D(f)=\mathbb{A}^n\setminus Z(f)$$
Then $D(f)\subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$ is open.

We can consider $\mathbb{A}^n$ as a subavariety of $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$. Consider the polynomial ring of $n+1$ variables $k[x_1,\dots, x_n, y]$ which corresponds to $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$. We know that $Z(fy-1)\subseteq \mathbb{A}^{n+1}$ is homeomorphic to $D(f)\subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$. This means that we can consider $D(f)$ as a closed subset of $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$.

Fact from topology:

> Let $C\subseteq Y\subseteq X$. If $C$ is closed in $X$, then $C$ is closed in $Y$.

Since $D(f)$ is closed in $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$, shouldn't it be closed in $\mathbb{A}^n$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The set $Z(fy-1)$ is *homeomorphic* to $D(f)$, but not *equal*!  While $Z(fy-1)$ is closed in $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$, $D(f)$ is not, and this is no contradiction since they are not actually the same set.

You may find it helpful to think about the following more familiar example.  An open interval $(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.  But $\mathbb{R}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$, while $(0,1)$ is not.

Answer (score 3):

> Let $C\subseteq Y\subseteq X$. If $C$ is closed in $X$, then $C$ is closed in $Y$.

If you are setting $Y = \mathbb A^n$, $X=\mathbb A^{n+1}$ and $C = D(f)$, then it is clear: $D(f)$ is not closed in $\mathbb A^{n+1}$ so the condition of your statement is not satisfied (But it is true that $D(f)$ is homeomorphic to a closed subset $Z(yf-1)$ of $\mathbb A^{n+1}$)

Comment: Do you mean closed subset of $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$ in the last sentence?